# Import Export both are not responding anything both is not working

Tags: php

Trying to export Magento single products but only a blank page is appearing. could not export any products either from **System ->Import/Export->Export** or from **System->Import/Export/Dataflow-profile**.

When trying to import just five products from **System ->Import/Export->Import** and by choosing a file to import when I click on "**check data**" button, file is just loading but it doesn't respond any thing, neither it generate any error/warning nor Import button is appearing.

I checked log file to see the error I got

```
 2014-05-08T09:33:05+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 58233  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 873

 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():     </catalog_product_view>  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                            ^  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 104: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():       <catalog_category_default>  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:      ^  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
```

Comment: which magneto version are you  using?

Comment: I'm using magento 1.7.0

Comment: ok..no one was answering over there thats why I asked it again..but u don't worry i'll remember it for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reasons that could be the cause are:

1. Incorrect CSV file formatting.
2. Issues with short descriptions
3. Issues with import/export paths
4. Problems with images locations

Comment: with the same csv format i have imported around 50 k data and it start arising this issue suddenly

Answer (score 0):

Check for any extension upgrade, or version upgrade.

Make sure the earlier csv format and current csv format are of same magento versions.

Comment: I could not export any single products. while m trying to export any products it providing me a blank page only. I have added some new attribute so I want to export a single products so that I can import new products in the same csv format